# How to update multiple columns from one table to another table using sql.?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to Update My 2 columns from `class_time_block` table into `class_time` table.

I have written some SQL code but it will never update both two columns in `class_time` table these two columns which I have to update:

1. Reason
2. Active_flg

when `class_time_block` table update then `class_time` table update. both are similer table but i want to update my `class_time` table when `class_time_block` table is updated.

```
UPDATE class_time
SET
    ( reason,
      active_flg ) = (
        SELECT
            reason,
            active_flg
        FROM
            class_time_block
        WHERE
            class_time_block.reason = class_time.reason
            AND class_time_block.active_flg = class_time.active_flg
    )
WHERE
    class_id = :class_id
    AND class_uid IS NOT NULL
    AND class_id IS NOT NULL
commit;
```

[image]

This is class time table

[image]

This is class_time_block

[image]

I want these two column data update into another table

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Comment: Providing example data for both tables would be useful.

Comment: Sorry but your explanation missing punctuation and hard to understand.

Comment: If you "want to update class_time table when class_time_block table is updated", then the thing you needed may be a trigger if you want them to be automatically updated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I have Attach images of my both tables

Comment: You're trying to update `reason`, `active_flg` columns while using them within the join condition of the subquery, Isn't that strange? Do they have a primary - foreign key relationship such as `class_time_block` has a class_time_ID column ?

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan yes class_uid,class_time is PK

Answer (score 0):

you can use update with merge if using oracle , sample below

```
MERGE into table1 t1 
USING ( SELECT id,col1, col2 FROM table2 ) t2
   ON  (t1.id= t2.id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET t1.col1= t2.col1, t1.col2= t2.col2;
```

you can add WHERE clause as needed .

Comment: Error at Command Line : 22 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword
00969. 00000 -  "missing ON keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
eroor happend

Comment: Already tried error happend                                                                                  
MERGE into class_time t1 
USING ( SELECT seq,reason,active_flg FROM class_time_block ) t2
   ON  t1.seq= t2.seq 
 WHEN MATCHED SET t1.reason= t2.reason, t1.active_flg= t2.active_flg;

Comment: check brackets on ON clause .  refer https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537400200346640591 as another sample

Comment: MERGE into class_time t1 
USING ( SELECT rowid,reason,active_flg FROM class_time_block ) t2
   ON  (t1.class_uid= t2.class_uid)
 WHEN MATCHED SET t1.reason= t2.reason, t1.active_flg= t2.active_flg;

Comment: try MERGE into class_time t1 USING ( SELECT rowid,reason,active_flg FROM class_time_block ) t2 ON (t1.class_uid= t2.class_uid) WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET t1.reason= t2.reason, t1.active_flg= t2.active_flg

Comment: if tables are not big then you can remove subquery as well 7 try  MERGE into class_time t1 USING class_time_block  t2 ON (t1.class_uid= t2.class_uid) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.reason= t2.reason, t1.active_flg= t2.active_flg

Answer (score 0):

As `SEQ` columns are common primary key identity columns for both of the tables, you can use the following Update statement with the proper aliasing including a subquery along with `EXISTS` clause :

```
UPDATE class_time ct
   SET (ct.reason, ct.active_flg) =
              ( SELECT reason, active_flg
                  FROM class_time_block ctb
                 WHERE ctb.seq = ct.seq)
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM class_time_block ctb 
                 WHERE ctb.seq = ct.seq )
   AND ct.class_id = :i_class_id --'mtm.online2020' (a sample value stated in the picture)
   AND ct.class_id IS NOT NULL
   AND ct.class_uid IS NOT NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d77c2b598e81434454bf7e25a85ff1a7)</kbd>

Comment: this error happened  Error report -
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: but @Faizan , I already showed it works in the demo (*data brought from your images*), please share your sample data set(*if exists any different one*) within a fiddle like this demo.